# FragementTransaction - detach versus hide

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction

According to the documentation the view hierarchy is destroyed on calling `FragmentTransaction.detach(Fragment)` and the view is hidden on calling `FragmentTransaction.hide(Fragment)`.
When will we use one over the other. From the user perspective, both will result in the same behaviour.